# @AssociationOverride does not create @JoinColumn from scratch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a group of tables, that are all identical apart from their owner table, and the corresponding foreign keys to that table. I made it all generic thanks to Hibernate/JPA, but cannot pass the `@JoinColumn` information via `@AssociationOverride` since the `name` value for it is ignored, or not overridden at all.

For example;

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "etc")
@AssociationOverride(name = "parent", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
public class RealEntity extends BaseEntity<ParentEntity, String> {
}
```

with;

```
@Data
@MappedSuperClass
public class BaseEntity<K, P> implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected Key<K> key = new Key<>();

    @MapsId("fk")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    protected P parent;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class Key<K> implements Serializable {

        protected K fk;

        @Column(name = "sub_id")
        protected String subId;
    }
}
```

parent:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parentc")
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    protected String parentId;
}
```

So as you see, it works well except for the parent's fk reference definition, I get mapping error since Hibernate tries to find a `parent_id`, rather than just `id` for the foreignKey, since `@JoinColumn` override is ignored. It works if I put the parent information in the `RealEntity` directly (obviously), or if I put `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` on `parent` in `BaseEntity` but I want to keep it as generic as possible. Is there any solution to this issue? Or should I just give up?

***edit***: it seems when I put a proper `@JoinColumn` with acceptable mapping for joining on `parent` in `BaseEntity`, that does get overridden, so it needs something valid to override. I cannot just add an association from nothingness is that the case? I've seen many examples on the web where they were putting associations from scratch, my usage of `@MapsId`, might be breaking the usage I guess. But I cannot change my current structure, since it is necessary to be able to represent composite foreign key definition for dependent child tables... I feel like there is a very simple solution, or some hacky way to achieve what I want, and I cannot seem to find it!